# I have a problem using the contextual menu in ChromiumWebBrowser. It doesn't recognize it. I'm using version 91 of CefSharp

Tags: c#

```
public class ContextMenuHandler : IContextMenuHandler
        {
            public void OnBeforeContextMenu(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IContextMenuParams parameters, IMenuModel model)
            {
                // ..
                model.Clear();
                model.AddItem((CefMenuCommand)26501, "copy");
                model.AddItem((CefMenuCommand)26502, "Paste");
                model.AddItem((CefMenuCommand)26503, "All");
            }

            // ...
            // ...
        }

 public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
chromiumWebBrowser1.MenuHandler = new ContextMenuHandler();

 }
```

I already have the libraries, but in this case, it doesn't recognize it. I saw the documentation, but I can't find where it recognizes IContextMenuHandler.

I should be able to open the contextual menu with this, but I'm not sure. I'm basing my code on a different version.